# Swift - How to access navigation item (Edit) from view controller that has a container view embedded inside of it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, container-view

the question may seem a little confusing so I'll simplify.

I have created a view controller (JournalViewController) that holds 2 container views (MealPlanViewController, ExerciseViewController - you can ignore this container). The MealPlanViewController has a UITableView and I want to be able to delete/move the rows of the UITableview by using the left navigation Edit button item. However, when I create the navigation item in the JournalViewController, I do not know how to make it editable with the container view's UITableView.

Here is an example:

[image]

Here is my JournalViewController class:

```
import UIKit

class JournalViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var exerciseContainerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var mealContainerView: UIView!

@IBOutlet var mealOrExerciseControl: UISegmentedControl!

var mealScheduleTableView: UITableView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func showComponent(sender: UISegmentedControl)
{
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
    {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations:
        {
                self.exerciseContainerView.alpha = 0
                self.mealContainerView.alpha = 1
                self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
        })
    }

    else
    {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations:
        {
                self.exerciseContainerView.alpha = 1
                self.mealContainerView.alpha = 0
                self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        })
    }
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the mealPlanViewController class you would set an IBAction for when the user presses the edit button.  Within the IBAction you can call any functions you want that impact the Tableview.

```
  @IBAction func editTable() {
          tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)

  }
```

After this your TableDelegate functions take over for deleting and moving rows.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but if I do that, how would I call the `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool` method?  Since that method is needed to activate the options to delete and/or move tableview cells.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And I apologize since I'm pretty new to this, but how do I connect the edit button programmatically from within the ScheduleViewController? Or do I need to specify and create the button inside of the storyboard itself?